# Paypal - Revise Subscription by changing the plan or quantity

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am new with paypal integration, everything is working fine but I stucked at the point where I want to update subscription's `quantity` and `plan` separately.

I went through the [official integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#revise-subscription)  and I found api for the case https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_revise.

Now when I am trying with the above rest api then facing below response (for both quantity and plan) `Payment in progress` each time

Please tell me where i am wrong, help me, thanks

[image]

Comment: I've seen this elsewhere, did you solve it yet @harish ?

Comment: I did a lot of struggles for PayPal and related things, mainly for subscriptions but finally, I moved to Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

The error "PAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS" is returned if you attempt to revise the billing details for a subscription within 24 hours of the next scheduled billing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).